# while loop unresponsive java when receiving option

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to receive the selected option from a custom JFrame in Java. The code works fine as expected when running in debug mode in netbeans (when there is a breakpoint inside the loop) but not in real time.

```
boolean keepgoing = true;
while (keepgoing) {
    if (ioFrame.getOption() == 0) {
        ioFrame.setVisible(false);
        keepgoing = false;
        //more code
    }
    else if (ioFrame.getOption() == 1) {
        ioFrame.setVisible(false);
        keepgoing = false; 
        //more code
    }         
}
```

`ioFrame.getOption()` returns -1 until a button is clicked on the JFrame, then depending on the button clicked it is either 0 or 1.

ioFrame Action Listeners:

```
JButton loadButton = new JButton("Load Inventory");
class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
{  
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {  
        initialOption = 0;
    }
}
loadButton.addActionListener(new ChoiceListener());

JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update Inventory");
class ChoiceListener2 implements ActionListener
{  
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {  
        initialOption = 1;
    }
}
updateButton.addActionListener(new ChoiceListener2());
```

Comment: You should use event handling instead of a while loop. See this for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: Try to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for better help. With that code i can't say you anything is not clear at all.

Comment: Like svz suggested, better use events - it's a bad practice to use busy-wait: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Comment: Which event listener should i use? i'm using event listeners in the custom JFrame class to set the 'option'. how would i go about detecting this in the calling class?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something returns -1 it usually means that the object is not existing or it is not there. Are you sure that you did not forget to initialize the Object/Variable you need? In debug mode, Netbeans do a lot of work for you(even initializing something) which is not done when code is compiled and executed without IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, I think the problem comes from the fact that your loop should require almost all of your computer resources. It never stops looping!

The problem is that you didn't provide any piece of code concerning `ioframe`.

If it is editable and the option value is given by a `JCheckbox` (we call `chk` here).
You could add a listener (`ItemListener`, `Actionlistener`...).

Here is an example to be implemented in ioFrame:

```
chk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setVisible(chk.isSelected());
    }
});
```

Another approach could be the creation of methods in ioFrame allowing to add listners to its components.

```
public void addVisibleChkActionListener(ActionListener ac){
    chk.addActionListener(ac);
}
```